# If allocation is random, what is the probability that at least one new member is assigned to each country?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Tech Gen is looking for more people to work at 5 different countries, and there are 10 applicants. Assume that all countries have at least 10 vacancies.

I know the solution should be like 1-(probability that none are assigned to any of countries)/5^10

But how to calculate that probability that none is assigned? Or, how to calculate that each is assigned?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle?

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{5}{k}$ ways to exclude $k$ of the countries from receiving an applicant and $(5 - k)^{10}$ ways to assign the employees to the remaining $5 - k$ countries.  Therefore, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of assignments with at least one person assigned to each of the five countries is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{5} (-1)^k\binom{5}{k}(5 - k)^{10} = 5^{10} - \binom{5}{1}4^{10} + \binom{5}{2}3^{10} - \binom{5}{3}2^{10} + \binom{5}{4}1^{10}$$
Since there are $5^{10}$ ways to assign ten applicants to five countries, the probability that each country receives at least one applicant is 
$$\frac{5^{10} - \binom{5}{1}4^{10} + \binom{5}{2}3^{10} - \binom{5}{3}2^{10} + \binom{5}{4}1^{10}}{5^{10}}$$

Comment: idk how I missed seeing your answer. (+1) I am letting my answer remain  because of the other (less efficient) method added.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

[all ways - at least $1$ room vacant + at least $2$ rooms vacant - at least $3$ rooms vacant + ....]/$5^{10}$

The numerator would be $5^{10} - \binom 51 4^{10} + \binom52 3^{10} - \binom53 2^{10} + \binom54 1^{10} = 5,103,000$

---

**ADDED**

If you don't know the inclusion-exclusion principle,
list patterns of no room empty, and find numerator as

[Choose people for particular rooms $1-5$] $\times$ [permute]

The patterns with one example worked out are

$6-1-1-1-1$
$5-2-1-1-1$
$4-3-1-1-1$
$4-2-2-1-1: \binom{10}{4,2,2,1,1}\times \frac{5!}{1!2!2!}= 1,134, 000$
$3-3-2-1-1$
$3-2-2-2-1$
$2-2-2-2-2$